# (python) selenium ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, element

need help please,
im going to automate roll date picker like that site, example i want to choose '2019' with this code but error. Any suggestion, thankyou

```
url = "https://www.cssscript.com/demo/mobile-ios-date-picker-rolldate/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

### Click on YYYY-MM-DD dateformat
choose_format = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input" ).click()
time.sleep(2)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[20]"))) ### choose 2019
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: java script can ease the code here and increase its success rate, for example `date_to_chage='2019-01-09'
my_js='''document.querySelector(\"input[placeholder='YYYY-MM-DD'\").value='{}' '''.format(date_to_chage)
driver.execute_script(my_js)`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.cssscript.com/demo/mobile-ios-date-picker-rolldate/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "date-group1-2").click()
time.sleep(1)
action = ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[text()='2024']")
action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(element, 0, 0).perform()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Confirm']").click()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Explanation:**
My apologies, my previous solution using JS was not reliable and intermittently working. I have updated the answer with a solution using `ActionChains` class. This works fine, however may not be the best solution, still works. Keep an eye on other answers if you receive any, you may get more robust solution.

**On another note, suggestion:**

Avoid using absolute XPATH expressions like below:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[20]
```

Instead use relative XPATH as below, these are more reliable.

```
//li[text()='2019']
```

Comment: hallo mate, thankyou for suggestion, it works but doesnt go to specific year, 

i tried like this 
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[text()='2024']")
but choose 2019

i keep trying, thank you :D

Comment: Just use the code as it is, use `"//li[text()='2024']"`. This line of code `action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(element, 0, 0).perform()` will drag the mouse to `2019`. Ensure you start the browser in full screen mode. `driver.maximize_window()`. Let me know the status.